# How to preserve two way binded value when changing both datacontext and items source of WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, combobox

**Background**

The application has a list view binded to a list of "Jobs", of which the properties are editable by some comboboxes (with two way binding). The data context of the comboboxes is changed to the currently selected `job` via the `SelectionChanged` event of the list view.

The combobox value is bound to a property of Job. The `itemssource` of the job is changed to completely different list upon `DataContextChanged`.

[Layout of widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxWqo.png)

**Issue**

The binded property linked to the combobox of Job is set to null when changing the DataContext.

By clicking through the list of Jobs, all the properties bound to any combobox are set to null.

**Assumed Problem**

*I may be incorrect in this assumtion...*

As the `datacontext` is switched, either the old selected `Job` or the new selected `Job` is set to null as the itemsource does nto contain the value stores in on of the either the new or old selected `Job`.

**Debugging Attempts (Edit)**

I've noticed the the value of the property of the `Job` was set to null before the `SelectedItem` of the list of jobs was changed.

**Question**

How can the value of the binded property of `Job` be preserved when switching the datacontext of the ComboBox to an itemsource that does not contain `SelectedValue`?

**Relevant Code (Abridged - Binding to other widgets works as expected)**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ContactField" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="3" Margin="2,1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding Contact,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="ContactField_SelectionChanged"/>
```

*Code Behind - Changing Items Source*

```
private void UpdateCustomerDependancies() 
{

    imprintDataSetTableAdapters.CustomerContactsTableTableAdapter rpcdtta = new imprintDataSetTableAdapters.CustomerContactsTableTableAdapter();
    IList<ComboData> customers = new List<ComboData>();

    if (LeftFieldPanel.DataContext != null) //Where LeftFieldPanel contains all comboboxes
    {
        Job currentJob = (Job)LeftFieldPanel.DataContext;

        foreach (DataRow item in rpcdtta.GetDataBy(currentJob.CustomerCode).Rows)
        {
            customers.Add(new ComboData() { Id = item.ItemArray[0].ToString(), Value = item.ItemArray[1].ToString() });
        }
        ContactField.ItemsSource = customers;

    }
}
```

*Code Behind - Changing Data Context*

```
private void jobTree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if (jobTree.SelectedItem.GetType() == typeof(Job))
        {
            DelGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;


            Job j = (Job)jobTree.SelectedItem;


            MessageBox.Show(j.Contact);

            LeftFieldPanel.DataContext = j; //Switch datacontext
            RightFieldPanel.DataContext = j; //switchdata context

        }


    }
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code? Did you debug the code? What did you notice during debugging? What approach did you try to solve the issue?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have added code context. Results of debugging have been summarised, however tracking the change of values in this circumstance is rather challenging. Failed attempts to solve issue included breaking MCV/MVVM to override the Text value of the ComboBox. A desired solution could not be reached.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26376944/5086631) you can't set `SelectedItem` to something that isn't contained in `ItemsSource` (unless you make the `CombboBox.IsEditable` property `true`, in which case the user can enter anything they want into the box).

Comment: @KeithStein I would concur according to my efforts and other research. I'm working on developing a workaround involving saving the old list before the binding changes, then removing any mismatching items. It certainly won't be pretty, but hopefully the answer will help someone else on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26376944/5086631), and my own research, it is not possible to simply bind and hope for this best. Therefore, my workaorund to this solution is the following. I have generalised the code to make it applicable to other circumstances.

1) Upon the change of datacontext, append new items to the list, without removing old items:

```
private void ListView1_SelectedItemChanged(...) {
    List<ComboData> comboitems = ((IList<ComboData>)ComboBox1.ItemsSource).ToList(); 
    //Add new items to comboitems here
    ComboBox1.ItemsSource = comboitems; //Rebind
}
```

2) Upon opening the dropdown of the combobox, get the itemsource and remove old items only

```
private void ComboBox1_DropDownOpened(...) {
    List<ComboData> comboitems = ((IList<ComboData>)ComboBox1.ItemsSource).ToList(); 
    //Remove old items from comboitems here
    ComboBox1.ItemsSource = comboitems; //Rebind
}
```

Apologies if this is not clear enough, I felt that posting the real code would make it rather difficult to understand out of the context.

This has solved my own issue.

**Alternate Solution**

See above and add items without remove old ones. Then replace the entire itemssource only on a `dropdownopened` event.